# Scale a gameobject on a keypress using acceleration/deceleration?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

This might be a stupid question, but is it possible to use [transform.localScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) along with acceleration?
I can increase/decrease the height of my gameobject on certain keypresses, but I want the scaling to speed up gradually until it reaches a certain speed, and when I release the key I want the scaling to decelerate before it stops completely. Right now my gameobject scales instantly, which is not very realistic.

This is the code I have so far:

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
        transform.localScale += new Vector3(0, -0.1f, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Time.deltaTime with some multiplicator in your Update() function to smooth your transformation from frame to frame